# No threads to run a task? I try to use Docker to run distributed training, but failed

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, distributed-training, gns3

1. use docker in the GNS3 VM
2. code run in 2 containers
3. I want to try the pytorch tutorial [IMPLEMENTING A PARAMETER SERVER USING DISTRIBUTED RPC FRAMEWORK](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/rpc_param_server_tutorial.html)but the trainer container gives this error

```
Rank 1 training batch 0 loss 2.3123748302459717
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/rpc_wk.py", line 238, in run_worker
    run_training_loop(rank, num_gpus, train_loader, test_loader)
  File "/home/rpc_wk.py", line 193, in run_training_loop
    dist_autograd.backward(cid, [loss])
RuntimeError: No threads to run a task
```

4. this is my code

```
import argparse
import os
import time
from threading import Lock

import torch
import torch.distributed.autograd as dist_autograd
import torch.distributed.rpc as rpc
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import optim
from torch.distributed.optim import DistributedOptimizer
from torchvision import datasets, transforms


# --------- MNIST Network to train, from pytorch/examples -----

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_gpus=0):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        print(f"Using {num_gpus} GPUs to train")
        self.num_gpus = num_gpus
        device = torch.device(
            "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() and self.num_gpus > 0 else "cpu")
        print(f"Putting first 2 convs on {str(device)}")
        # Put conv layers on the first cuda device, or CPU if no cuda device
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1).to(device)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1).to(device)
        # Put rest of the network on the 2nd cuda device, if there is one
        if "cuda" in str(device) and num_gpus > 1:
            device = torch.device("cuda:1")

        print(f"Putting rest of layers on {str(device)}")
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout2d(0.25).to(device)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout2d(0.5).to(device)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9216, 128).to(device)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10).to(device)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)

        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        # Move tensor to next device if necessary
        next_device = next(self.fc1.parameters()).device
        x = x.to(next_device)

        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        output = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
        return output


# --------- Helper Methods --------------------

# On the local node, call a method with first arg as the value held by the
# RRef. Other args are passed in as arguments to the function called.
# Useful for calling instance methods. method could be any matching function, including
# class methods.
def call_method(method, rref, *args, **kwargs):
    return method(rref.local_value(), *args, **kwargs)


# Given an RRef, return the result of calling the passed in method on the value
# held by the RRef. This call is done on the remote node that owns
# the RRef and passes along the given argument.
# Example: If the value held by the RRef is of type Foo, then
# remote_method(Foo.bar, rref, arg1, arg2) is equivalent to calling
# <foo_instance>.bar(arg1, arg2) on the remote node and getting the result
# back.

def remote_method(method, rref, *args, **kwargs):
    args = [method, rref] + list(args)
    return rpc.rpc_sync(rref.owner(), call_method, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)


# --------- Parameter Server --------------------
class ParameterServer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_gpus=0):
        super().__init__()
        model = Net(num_gpus=num_gpus)
        self.model = model
        self.input_device = torch.device(
            "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() and num_gpus > 0 else "cpu")

    def forward(self, inp):
        inp = inp.to(self.input_device)
        out = self.model(inp)
        # This output is forwarded over RPC, which as of 1.5.0 only accepts CPU tensors.
        # Tensors must be moved in and out of GPU memory due to this.
        out = out.to("cpu")
        return out

    # Use dist autograd to retrieve gradients accumulated for this model.
    # Primarily used for verification.
    def get_dist_gradients(self, cid):
        grads = dist_autograd.get_gradients(cid)
        # This output is forwarded over RPC, which as of 1.5.0 only accepts CPU tensors.
        # Tensors must be moved in and out of GPU memory due to this.
        cpu_grads = {}
        for k, v in grads.items():
            k_cpu, v_cpu = k.to("cpu"), v.to("cpu")
            cpu_grads[k_cpu] = v_cpu
        return cpu_grads

    # Wrap local parameters in a RRef. Needed for building the
    # DistributedOptimizer which optimizes paramters remotely.
    def get_param_rrefs(self):
        param_rrefs = [rpc.RRef(param) for param in self.model.parameters()]
        return param_rrefs


# The global parameter server instance.
param_server = None
# A lock to ensure we only have one parameter server.
global_lock = Lock()


def get_parameter_server(num_gpus=0):
    """
    Returns a singleton parameter server to all trainer processes
    """
    global param_server
    # Ensure that we get only one handle to the ParameterServer.
    with global_lock:
        if not param_server:
            # construct it once
            param_server = ParameterServer(num_gpus=num_gpus)
        return param_server


def run_parameter_server(rank, world_size):
    # The parameter server just acts as a host for the model and responds to
    # requests from trainers.
    # rpc.shutdown() will wait for all workers to complete by default, which
    # in this case means that the parameter server will wait for all trainers
    # to complete, and then exit.
    print("PS master initializing RPC")
    os.environ['GLOO_SOCKET_IFNAME'] = 'eth0'
    os.environ['TP_SOCKET_IFNAME'] = 'eth0'
    options = rpc.TensorPipeRpcBackendOptions(num_worker_threads=256, rpc_timeout=60 * 60, init_method="tcp://1.1.1.10:56789", _transports=["uv"],)
    rpc.init_rpc(name="parameter_server", rank=rank, world_size=world_size, rpc_backend_options=options)
    print("RPC initialized! Running parameter server...")
    rpc.shutdown()
    print("RPC shutdown on parameter server.")


# --------- Trainers --------------------

# nn.Module corresponding to the network trained by this trainer. The
# forward() method simply invokes the network on the given parameter
# server.
class TrainerNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_gpus=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_gpus = num_gpus
        self.param_server_rref = rpc.remote(
            "parameter_server", get_parameter_server, args=(num_gpus,))

    def get_global_param_rrefs(self):
        remote_params = remote_method(
            ParameterServer.get_param_rrefs,
            self.param_server_rref)
        return remote_params

    def forward(self, x):
        model_output = remote_method(
            ParameterServer.forward, self.param_server_rref, x)
        return model_output


def run_training_loop(rank, num_gpus, train_loader, test_loader):
    # Runs the typical nueral network forward + backward + optimizer step, but
    # in a distributed fashion.
    net = TrainerNet(num_gpus=num_gpus)
    # Build DistributedOptimizer.
    param_rrefs = net.get_global_param_rrefs()
    opt = DistributedOptimizer(optim.SGD, param_rrefs, lr=0.03)
    for i, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        with dist_autograd.context() as cid:
            model_output = net(data)
            target = target.to(model_output.device)
            loss = F.nll_loss(model_output, target)
            if i % 5 == 0:
                print(f"Rank {rank} training batch {i} loss {loss.item()}")
            dist_autograd.backward(cid, [loss])
            # Ensure that dist autograd ran successfully and gradients were
            # returned.
            assert remote_method(
                ParameterServer.get_dist_gradients,
                net.param_server_rref,
                cid) != {}
            opt.step(cid)

    print("Training complete!")
    print("Getting accuracy....")
    get_accuracy(test_loader, net)


def get_accuracy(test_loader, model):
    model.eval()
    correct_sum = 0
    # Use GPU to evaluate if possible
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if model.num_gpus > 0
                                      and torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i, (data, target) in enumerate(test_loader):
            out = model(data)
            pred = out.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
            pred, target = pred.to(device), target.to(device)
            correct = pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()
            correct_sum += correct

    print(f"Accuracy {correct_sum / len(test_loader.dataset)}")


# Main loop for trainers.
def run_worker(rank, world_size, num_gpus, train_loader, test_loader):
    print(f"Worker rank {rank} initializing RPC")
    os.environ['GLOO_SOCKET_IFNAME'] = 'eth0'
    os.environ['TP_SOCKET_IFNAME'] = 'eth0'
    options = rpc.TensorPipeRpcBackendOptions(num_worker_threads=256, rpc_timeout=60 * 60, init_method="tcp://1.1.1.10:56789", _transports=["uv"],)
    rpc.init_rpc(
        name=f"trainer_{rank}",
        rank=rank,
        world_size=world_size,
        rpc_backend_options=options)

    print(f"Worker {rank} done initializing RPC")

    run_training_loop(rank, num_gpus, train_loader, test_loader)
    rpc.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Parameter-Server RPC based training")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--world_size",
        type=int,
        default=4,
        help="""Total number of participating processes. Should be the sum of
        master node and all training nodes.""")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--rank",
        type=int,
        default=None,
        help="Global rank of this process. Pass in 0 for master.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--num_gpus",
        type=int,
        default=0,
        help="""Number of GPUs to use for training, Currently supports between 0
         and 2 GPUs. Note that this argument will be passed to the parameter servers.""")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--master_addr",
        type=str,
        default="1.1.1.10",
        help="""Address of master, will default to localhost if not provided.
        Master must be able to accept network traffic on the address + port.""")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--master_port",
        type=str,
        default="56789",
        help="""Port that master is listening on, will default to 29500 if not
        provided. Master must be able to accept network traffic on the host and port.""")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    assert args.rank is not None, "must provide rank argument."
    assert args.num_gpus <= 3, f"Only 0-2 GPUs currently supported (got {args.num_gpus})."
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = args.master_addr
    os.environ["MASTER_PORT"] = args.master_port

processes = []
world_size = args.world_size
if args.rank == 0:
    p = mp.Process(target=run_parameter_server, args=(0, world_size))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
else:
    # Get data to train on
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        datasets.MNIST('/home', train=True, download=False,
                       transform=transforms.Compose([
                           transforms.ToTensor(),
                           transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                       ])),
        batch_size=32, shuffle=False, )
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        datasets.MNIST(
            '/home',
            train=False,
            transform=transforms.Compose([
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
            ])),
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=False,
    )
    # start training worker on this node
    p = mp.Process(
        target=run_worker,
        args=(
            args.rank,
            world_size, args.num_gpus,
            train_loader,
            test_loader))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

I searched that multi-threaded process can run in a docker container. And I have tried such as add

```
RUN ulimit -n int
```

to the dockerfile, and install dumb-init in my container. But it still can not work.